# mysql_ to PDO migration issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, migration

I'm having some issue trying to migrating from mysql_ to PDO (I'm new with it).

I've already done the most of the work, but there's a function that's driving me crazy.

Here it is:

```
function fields($thequery) /* SELECT * FROM table */
{
    $fields=array();
    $fields['num']=mysql_num_fields($thequery);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $fields['num']; $i++) {
        $fields['data'][]=mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

I've tried to read some other posts but I can't figure it out.

This is the best I can at the moment, but I always get **undefined index "num".**

```
function fields($thequery)
{
    global $pdo; /* Connection */

    $result = $pdo->prepare($thequery);
    $result->execute();
    $fields['num'] = $result->rowCount();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $fields['num']; $i++) {
        $fields['data'][]=$result->getColumnMeta($i);
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

What am I doing wrong with this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the use of such a peculiar function?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I noticed you deleted your comments under Jay's answer. Funny that; there's a green tick next to it. Eating your words I take it? I also take it those (now deleted) words taste a bit bitter huh? Sort of like vinegar you might say? *lol* Rich; looks good on you. Don't you just love it when people are right and you wrong? Oh, but you won't admit that nor retract your downvote from his answer. NooOOoooo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. First, you don't declare the fields array in your second function, `$fields = array();`, and then you have an issue when counting the rows:

```
$result->rowCount();
```

Your query is likely a `SELECT` query, which will not work with `rowCount()`

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

For `SELECT` when you are not doing a `COUNT()` query you can return the number of rows like this after `$result->execute();`

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
$num_rows = count($rows);
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah, seeing you think you're such a DB God. *"What's the use of such a peculiar function?"* - You should be able to figure it out. But, what's it to you anyway? You should make it a habit to live and let live instead of spreading bad karma around.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think you've got the point, because I was using SELECT * to get the number of rows in that table. I will try as you said on tuesday, because I have all files locally stored in office, and I'll confirm you.

Comment: @NtnRanger have you gotten a chance to test this?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes, I've tested it, you and Darwin von Corax were right

Comment: @JayBlanchard Funny, where did that "common friend" of ours go and his comments? I guess he's gone back to Momma crying *"Mwaaahhh, mommy the guy was right, what should I do??? I've been shamed I say, shamed and Jay was right all along... MwAaaaaawwwwww MOMMY!!!!!"*

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem; you're calling `PDOStatement::rowCount()` when you mean to call `PDOStatement::columnCount()`.

Your code should be

```
function fields($thequery)
{
    global $pdo; /* Connection */

    $result = $pdo->prepare($thequery);
    $result->execute();
    $fields['num'] = $result->columnCount();  // Change this line
    for ($i = 0; $i < $fields['num']; $i++)
    {
        $fields['data'][] = $result->getColumnMeta($i);
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Note that [the documentation for `PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) contains the following warnings:

> **Warning** This function is *EXPERIMENTAL*. The behaviour of this function,
> its name, and surrounding documentation may change without notice in a
> future release of PHP. This function should be used at your own risk.
>
> **Warning** Not all PDO drivers support **PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()**.

Comment: Well, what I tried to get with rowCount() was the number of rows in a table, with SELECT * query and not the number of columns.

Comment: The function you've shown us retrieves the column metadata *for each column;* for that you need the number of *columns*, not the number of *rows.* If you want the number of rows you should use a completely separate function, since the number of rows is orthogonal to the number of columns or the column metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tried out what Jay Blanchard and Darwin von Corax said.

The problem was the array (I've forgot to declare it) and columnCount().

The biggest problem was that I misunderstood the function. I was sure that it was counting the rows...I don't know why, looks logic now!

```
function fields($thequery) {
   global $pdo;

   $result = $pdo->prepare($thequery);
   $fields = array();
   $result->execute();
   $fields['num'] = $result->rowCount();
   for ($i = 0; $i < $fields['num']; $i++) {
      $fields['data'][]=$result->getColumnMeta($i);
   }
   return $fields;  }
```

Comment: There is no problem with array declaration. thus this answer adds nothing to the Darwin's one.

Comment: Yeah, but at least this guy admitted his mistake @YourCommonSense when you never do; that's just your "common nature". Oh and I upvoted this, in order to balance out your downvote.

Comment: @YourCommonSense what's your problem? I just added this answer to post the complete corrected answer, based on what the other two guys said (and I replied to every comment to say they where right). WTF